# Is a cooling fan on my Nema34 driver necessary?

Tags: power-supply, stepper-driver

I'm driving my Nema34 with a 3-phase driver seen below. It has a small cooling fan which produces unnecessary noise. The driver also has a heat sink across all front cover (on which the fan is attached). The heat sink is cold during the operation of the driver.

Is it safe for me to remove the fan? What should I consider when making the decision? I also don't see any temperature requirements in the datasheet, so I don't know how high the temperate is okay to go.

[image: Nema Driver]

Comment: Possibly, if you are running significantly under capacity at all times and in open air because there's a chance the fan is only there for running in a vented enclosure. Check installation instructions in the manual. When it's going to bite you is the occasional peak load.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to ignore the noise but you ruled that out. I would simply replace the fan with one that makes a lot less noise. Removing it would work but do you have the resources to properly derate it. Without the fan it will change the operating temperature to a lower number and lower the electrical output ratings.